# Swift: Error converting type 'Binding<Subject>' when passing Observed object's property to child view

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui

I want to load data from an API, then pass that data to several child views.
Here's a minimal example with one child view (`DetailsView`). I am getting this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Subject>' to expected argument type 'BusinessDetails'
```

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Alamofire

struct BusinessView: View {
    var shop: Business
    
    class Observer : ObservableObject{
        @Published public var shop = BusinessDetails()
        @Published public var loading = false
        
        init(){ shop = await getDetails(id: shop.id) }
        
        func getDetails(id: String) async -> (BusinessDetails) {
            let params = [
                id: id
            ]
            
            self.loading = true
            self.shop = try await AF.request("https://api.com/details", parameters: params).serializingDecodable(BusinessDetails.self).value
            self.loading = false

            return self.shop
        }
    }
    
    @StateObject var observed = Observer()
    
    var body: some View {
        if !observed.loading {
            TabView {
                DetailsView(shop: $observed.shop)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Details", systemImage: "")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This has worked before when the Observed object's property wasn't an object itself (like how the `loading` property doesn't cause an error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using async/await you should use the `.task` modifier and remove the object. The task will be started when the view appears, cancelled when it disappears and restarted when the `id` changes. This saves you a lot of effort trying to link async task lifecycle to object lifecycle. e.g.

```
struct BusinessView: View {
    let shop: Business
    @State var shopDetails = BusinessDetails()
    @State var loading = false
    
    var body: some View {
        if loading {
            Text("Loading")
        } 
        else {
            TabView {
                DetailsView(shop: shopDetails)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Details", systemImage: "")
                    }
            }
        }
        .task(id: shop.id) {
            loading = true
            shopDetails = await Self.getDetails(id: shop.id) // usually we have a try catch around this so we can show an error message
            loading = false
        }
    }

     // you can move this func somewhere else if you like
     static func getDetails(id: String) async -> BusinessDetails{
            let params = [
                id: id
            ]

            let result = try await AF.request("https://api.com/details", parameters: params).serializingDecodable(BusinessDetails.self).value
            
            return result
        }
    }
}
```